# how to enumerate all instances of SSRS, SSIS, SSAS, and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

looking to generate a listing of all SQL Server instances, showing

- machine name
- default or instance name
- type of component (Database Engine or SSRS or SSIS or SSAS)

is there a powershell script that does this, or will system center show all this?

Comment: any solution with full source code ps1 about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find it on a server or workstation, you can pop in the SQL disk, wait for the install center to come up and select Tools > Installed SQL Server features discovery report.

To check your whole network, check out [Microsoft MAP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx). Works for SQL 2008. It will check:

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows XP Professional
- Office 2010 and previous versions
- Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2003 R2
- Windows 2000 Professional or Windows 2000 Server
- VMware ESX
- VMware ESXi
- VMware Server
- Linux variants
- LAMP application stack discovery
- SQL Server 2008

I'm not sure about 2005/2000 besides db instances.  Those are easy to find with sqlcmd -L.  You could use wmi queries on specific servers to match service names.  I believe the sql active directory services may register the services in AD...but I don't think you can rely on that.